# Implementation problem of a PrimeNG Angular2 component with DynamicDialogRef and without DynamicDialogRef

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular2-components

I'm trying to implement a component with dynamic dialog and there is a need to use a direct usage. With the DynamicDialog example, there is a constructor of the car demo list component.
`constructor(private carService: CarService, public ref: DynamicDialogRef, public config: DynamicDialogConfig) { }`

When I use directly `<carlist></carlist>,`  I have an error like this:

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CarslistdemoComponent -> DynamicDialogRef]: 
>    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CarslistdemoComponent -> DynamicDialogRef]: 
>      NullInjectorError: No provider for DynamicDialogRef!
>      at NullInjector.push.../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get

Is there anyone can solve this problem or can you give advice to implement a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I learned, there is no way to implement in same component. I had to implement in seperate components. There is an answer related to this:

[Click to see answer](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=173729&sid=e9407bf797ba9777328afb994e2d809c#p173729)